# Error: The module depends on the missing object 'sysdb.ssma_oracle.db_check_init_package'

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration, data-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

i migrated an entire oracle Database to SQL Server 2014 Database  using SSMA.
(SQL Server Migration assistant)

The migration resulted in introduction of multiple Execution calls in my stored procedures (like below):

```
The module 'INFRA_IP_WEBLOGGER$spCheckIPStatus' depends on the missing object 'sysdb.ssma_oracle.db_check_init_package'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
The module 'INFRA_IP_WEBLOGGER$spCheckIPStatus' depends on the missing object 'sysdb.ssma_oracle.db_error_exact_one_row_check'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.
```

where INFRA_IP_WEBLOGGER$spCheckIPStatus is one of the Procedure name.

Do i have to install some seperate component so that SQL Server 2014 detects call to sysdb.ssma_oracle

What can i do to fix these errors?

Comment: Sadly, I cannot help You. From pure curiosity - why You have migrated from Oracle to MSSQL? Why...?

Comment: Giving support of both Oracle and SQL to my Product. (Application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMA relies on some stored procedures added to your SQL Server instance. Look at the manual for "Extension Pack" installation. Something for older version of SSMA is here on MSDN: [Installing SSMA Components on SQL Server (OracleToSQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313165%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) , but use the manual and extension pack for your specific SSMA version.

Comment: Is there some link available to download / install the extension pack?

Comment: SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) has own manual, extension pack is part of SSMA downloads. For example, if you used v5.3 for Oracle - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42655 , notice there are 2 installation files, one is for Extension Pack - "SSMA_Oracle\SSMA for Oracle.5.3.0.ExtPack.exe". But you need to install extension pack from the same version of SSMA that was used to convert the database.

Comment: Manual is embedded in SSMA, Help > Help (F1) and find "Installing SSMA Components on SQL Server (OracleToSQL)".